# SQL after update trigger between two tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables, `Engineering` and `Electrical`. Work is done in the `Engineering` table, then the `Electrical` team starts work after that. They share some of the same columns. Those columns are

```
Tag
Service Description
Horsepower
RPM
Project Number
```

I want to create an after update trigger so that when the `Tag` column gets filled in the `Electrical` table and that data matches the data in one of the `Tag` columns in the `Engineering` table, the other four same columns in the `Engineering` table automatically are sent to the corresponding columns in the `Electrical` table.

Below is what I tried which obviously doesn't work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Electrial_Update] 
ON [dbo].[ENGINEERING] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ELECTRICAL ([ICM_SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_],[PROJECT_NUMBER_], [ICM_POWER_HP_], [ICM_POWER_KW_], [ICM_RPM_])
        SELECT 
            i.[ICM_SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_], i.[PROJECT_NUMBER_],
            i.[ICM_POWER_HP_], i.[ICM_POWER_KW_], i.[ICM_RPM_]
        FROM 
            ENGINEERING m
        JOIN 
            inserted i ON i.[TAG_] = m.[TAG_]    
END
```

I'm someone trying to teach myself SQL on the fly so be kind. As always I'm very appreciative of any help.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post, I'm assuming you already have an entry in the `Electrical` table, and it's column `Tag` gets updated from `NULL` to some other value. This syntax is for **SQL Server** - you didn't explicitly specify what RDBMS you're using, but it looks like SQL Server to me. If it's not - adapt as needed.

Assuming you have only a single row in `Engineering` that matches that `Tag` value, you can do something like this - it has to be an **`UPDATE`** statement since you already have a row in `Electrical` - you want to **update** some columns, not insert a completely new row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Electrical_Update] 
ON [dbo].Electrical 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(Tag)
        UPDATE dbo.Electrical 
        SET [ICM_SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_] = eng.[ICM_SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_],
            [PROJECT_NUMBER_] = eng.[PROJECT_NUMBER_],
            [ICM_POWER_HP_] = eng.[ICM_POWER_HP_], 
            [ICM_POWER_KW_] = eng.[ICM_POWER_KW_], 
            [ICM_RPM_] = eng.[ICM_RPM_]
        FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN dbo.Engineering eng ON i.Tag = eng.Tag 
        WHERE Electrical.Tag = i.Tag;
END
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, there is already an Electrical table and it has rows in it. The Tag column will get updated to some value and will only have one matching record in the Mechanical table. This is for SQL Server. When I tried your script, it gave an error on the Where statement. It didn't like el.Tag. The error was the multi-part identifier could not be found. I assume that is because of the el. ???? I changed the script by adding [Electrial]. in front of the columns: SET [ELECTRICAL].[ICM_SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_] = i.[ICM_SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_], and that solved the error I was getting.

Comment: Although that solved the error issue, It still didn't work when I added data to the Tag column that matched a Tag column in the Engineering table. Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you for your reply and helping.

Comment: @Drafter-SQL: OK, updated my response - your trigger needs to be on the `Electrical` table (not the `Engineering` table), and it needs to join over to the `Engineering`  table to grab the values from there

Comment: Will SQL Server resolve the unqualified `Tag` reference back to the Electrical table referenced in the UPDATE or is it necessary to explicitly join the Electrical  table and reference the associated alias in the UPDATE - `UPDATE elec ... FROM Inserted i JOIN dbo.Electrical elec ON i.Tag = elec.Tag JOIN dbo.Engineering eng ON i.Tag = eng.Tag`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, that achieved the needed results I was looking for. This community is a blessing for someone like my trying to learn SQL on my own.  Thanks again.

Comment: @TN: the unqualified column names will always be referenced in the table that the trigger exists on - here `dbo.Electrical`

Comment: Maybe this is version specific. I get "Ambiguous column name 'Tag'." in SQL Server 2019. Do you have a reference for your stated "unqualified column name" behavior?